QGIS expression to symbolise road condition between values
I am using QGIS 3.22.16. I try to symbolize a road condition. The result wanted is:
Equal 2 if Minor > 0.3
Moderate > 0.2
severe > 0.1
Equal 1 if
0.2 < Minor <0.3
0.1 < Moderate <0.2
0 < Severe < 0.1
Equal 0 for else.
I used the open field calculator to type the expression. When I try to type all of it. I have some syntax error (see image).
Do I miss some brackets? Is the open field calculator the ideal place to write the expression?

Please edit your question by adding your expression as text, not just image

Your expression is all wrong : you are mixing CASE and IF syntax, you probably should use AND rather than OR if all condition should be true and you cant use two comparaison on the same value (use BETWEEN)...

Dont mix case when and if. You can use case when, take a look at this tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

There are multiple issues with your expression. As has been mentioned in the comments you seem to have misunderstood the CASE expression. A general tip in all these cases is to format your expression properly (by adding newlines and whitespace). Additionally, you are trying to do a < x < b, which is not possible in most languages, and needs to be broken up into a < x AND x < b.
Here is a working expression:
CASE
  WHEN "MinorPotho" > 0.3 OR "ModerPotho" > 0.2 OR "SeverPotho" > 0.1
  THEN 2
  WHEN "MinorPotho" > 0.2 OR "ModerPotho" > 0.1 OR "SeverPotho" > 0
  THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END

Observe how I've used whitespace and newlines to format the expression so that it is more readable. Since the case of "MinorPotho" > 0.3 is already covered by the first "branch" (the first WHEN) I do not need to check for that in the second branch. If MinorPotho is above 0.3 it will never even reach that point.
Symbology
However, since your question title says that you want to symbolize the layer you might not want/need to calculate a new field such as you're trying to do. Instead, you can use rule based symbology:

Open the symbology for the layer
Set it to Rule-based
Add a first rule with the test "MinorPotho" > 0.3 OR "ModerPotho" > 0.2 OR "SeverPotho" > 0.1 and the symbol you want
Add a second rule with the test ("MinorPotho" > 0.2 AND "MinorPotho" <= 0.3) OR ("ModerPotho" > 0.1 AND "ModerPotho" <= 0.2) OR ("SeverPotho" > 0 AND "SeverPotho" <= 0.1) and the symbol you want

Note that we here actually do have to check that the value is below as well. Note also that we use <= ("less than or equal") rather than <, otherwise 0.3/0.2/0.1 would not match neither of the two rules and go to the catch-all.


Finally, add a rule set to Else with the final symbology

